# How can I configure Dropbear SSH for Android NDK build?

Tags: android, eclipse, ssh, android-ndk, configure

I am trying to cross-compile the Dropbear SSH client from my Macintosh OS X Yosemite and the Android NDK v10 and Eclipse so that my Android application is able to SSH to another machine.  I am using the latest version of Dropbear, 2014.66.  I'm stuck on how to properly run `configure` to generate some files for this Android build.  Thus far, I'm invoking `configure` like this:

```
PATH=/Users/me/Development/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/:$PATH;
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-zlib
```

However, it fails with the output:

```
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/me/sds/flume/android/workspace/jni/dropbear':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

So I have not set up the cross-compilation environment correctly.  How can I set up my environment so that the NDK is set up so that `gcc` and any other build tools required are in my path?

Once I get `configure` properly run, I will use my `Android.mk` I have created based upon a v0.52 Android port of Dropbear together with the `ndk-build` command:

```
# jni/botan/Android.mk:
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := dropbear
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=\
    dbutil.c buffer.c \
    dss.c bignum.c \
    signkey.c rsa.c random.c \
    queue.c \
    atomicio.c compat.c  fake-rfc2553.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES+=\
    common-session.c packet.c common-algo.c common-kex.c \
    common-channel.c common-chansession.c termcodes.c \
    tcp-accept.c listener.c process-packet.c \
    common-runopts.c circbuffer.c

# loginrec.c 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES+=\
    cli-algo.c cli-main.c cli-auth.c cli-authpasswd.c cli-kex.c \
    cli-session.c cli-service.c cli-runopts.c cli-chansession.c \
    cli-authpubkey.c cli-tcpfwd.c cli-channel.c cli-authinteract.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES+=netbsd_getpass.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libtommath libtomcrypt

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug
LOCAL_MODULE := dropbear
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/libtommath 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/libtomcrypt/src/headers
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DDROPBEAR_CLIENT

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: Just a warning: NDK executables that work on L or newer will not work before ICS (PIE is required on L and newer, but PIE wasn't supported until ICS).

Comment: @DanAlbert If it is easy, please define the terms L, ICS, and PIE.  Could these be Lollipop, Ice Cream Sandwich, and ?

Comment: Lollipop, Ice Cream Sandwich, and [Position Independent Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables).

Comment: In this case, the `Android.mk` seems to only mention shared libraries, not standalone executables, so in that case, there wouldn't be any issue with PIE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/path/to/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm" ./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-zlib
```

(If configure tries to run C++ compilation as well, you'd need to add `CXX="arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/same/path"` as well before `./configure` in the command line.)

Alternatively, you can build a complete standalone toolchain where you don't need to specify the sysroot manually. You can build such a toolchain using the script  `<ndk>/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh` (see the "Standalone toolchain" topic in the NDK docs). However, if you are only going to use it for running configure, to generate `config.h` for building the rest using `Android.mk`, this is probably overkill.